# EE4 & Gmaps Plugin

Tags: error, google-maps-for-ee, ee4

[image]

This is the error I am getting when trying to install Gmaps by Reinos on EE4.

I'm getting a similar error when trying to install the Gmaps Data Plugin on EE4 as well.

[image]

Comment: It installs perfectly on EE3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change a little in code at **line 230** in `upd.gmaps` of your plugin directory.

```
'constraint' => '255' to 'constraint' => '191'
```

This need to change from **255** to **191** because there is `INNODB utf8mb4`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the code change was actually in settings.php for EE4 at line 167. I can now install Gmaps. I am however having a similar issue when installing the Gmaps Data plugin. Any thoughts on that? (See above screenshot I've added to my original post) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, same thing you need to do in Gmaps Data also. You need to change "constraint" of "lat", "lng", "city", "street_name", "country", "country_code", "search_location" from "200" to "191" in the "settings.php" which was located in the directory of Gamps Data plugin.

Comment: great! works for me too